# Maptopair transformation in spark taking a lot of time

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have written a job in apache spark and java 1.7. One of the steps of the job is to assign a counter to each RDDstring of 1 and then combining the common string and their counter, very much similar to wordcount job. But while assigning a value of 1 in the maptopair transformation its taking a lot of time. I have a total of 13900673 RDD count and I am running on a single node. My map to pair code looks like-

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> somePair=getoldRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {

            @Override
            public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String arg0) throws Exception {
                return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(arg0, 1);
            }
        });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the entire code? This looks normal